# Login process with Shiro takes too much time when CPU usage is 100%

Tags: java, spring, shiro

I use Apache Shiro 1.2.3 to control the login process in my application.
The application has a background process that feeds it with data to process; everything works fine when the application works with a low or mid data charge, but when the application receives a big amount of data to process, it starts to consume the 100% of the CPU.

One of the problem is if you try to log in the application while this is happening, the login process takes 20-35 seconds, (but when the CPU is free, it only takes about 0,5 seconds).
Searching inside the "conflictive" code, i've found this code that takes most of the login process time:

```
this.getCredentialsMatcher().doCredentialsMatch(token, info)
```

Basically, this code try to find out if the password stored in the database (the password is stored hashed with an SHA-512 algorithm with 100.000 iterations) matches with the password entered by the user in the login form.

I'm using a custom HashingPasswordService and here's the code of the passwordsMatch method:

```
public boolean passwordsMatch(Object plaintext, Hash saved) {

    ByteSource plaintextBytes = createByteSource(plaintext);

    if (saved == null || saved.isEmpty()) {
        return plaintextBytes == null || plaintextBytes.isEmpty();
    } else {
        if (plaintextBytes == null || plaintextBytes.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    HashRequest request = buildHashRequest(plaintextBytes, saved);

    Hash computed = this.hashService.computeHash(request);

    return saved.equals(computed);
}
```

Any ideas why the login process is taking so much time when the CPU is fully working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by 100000 iterations ?

Comment: I think he is talking about iterative hashing. The idea is simple: instead of taking just one SHA512 of the password, you take the SHA512 of the SHA512 of the SHA512 of the password. You repeatedly call SHA512 on the previous result

Comment: When you hash a password, you can specify the number of hash iterations to perform when computing hashes.